# Meanings of Colors in ankhsvn

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ankhsvn

What is the difference between a dark-blue 'Changed' and a grey 'Changed' Item in History Viewer?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't actually found documentation on this, but it **appears** that grey represents items that were included in the selected revision but were above the directory that you selected to view the history for.

For example, your project consists of the following structure:

```
Root
 - dir_a
     file_a.txt
   - dir_b
     - dir_c
         file_c.txt
```

If you click View History for dir_b, then a change to `file_c.txt` will appear in blue, but a change to `file_a.txt` will appear in grey (since it is above dir_b).  Clicking View History for dir_a will show both in blue.

Comment: Actually, some check-ins also appear in bold. Does anyone know meaning of that ?